# How can I automate fold markers at column 81?

Tags: vim

I am a big fan of using markers for defining folds (foldmethod = marker).
For presentation purpose, I always put the markers ({{{1, 2, etc) at column 81, which sometimes proves to be a bit tedious if a line is short.

So what script could automate this :

```
map %1 to : insert spaces up to column 81 then insert {{{1 then <CR>
map %2 to : insert spaces up to column 81 then insert {{{2 then <CR>
```

etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the line is shorter than 81 chars (or it will get truncated):

```
:nnoremap %1 080A <Esc>080lC{{{1<CR>
:nnoremap %2 080A <Esc>080lC{{{2<CR>

:inoremap %1 <Esc>080A <Esc>080lC{{{1<CR>
:inoremap %2 <Esc>080A <Esc>080lC{{{2<CR>
```

i'm not to sure that the `<CR>` is what you want (I'd expect a simple `<Esc>` to work better with my editing worflows)

Comment: Thanks, that works great. One question though: what if I want to use it in insert mode ?